# Puid is null/empty. Puid must be present in the header for user to get authorized

Tags: azure, rest, http, request, postman

I'm encountering a problem when I tried to ask he REST API from Microsoft Azure.
I want to get data about cost management from [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usagebyscope).
I'm using Postman.

Here is my auth request to have the auth token :

```
POST /0409a1ac-f7e5-42e3-bcf9-67b730924d00/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c387a38f-a7ec-4ea7-9496-b03c6ede7bf2,406a808c-8c32-4f85-b587-ebcb68f2245c
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; stsservicecookie=ests; fpc=AgTu1H7GJ8tPjlaIdg4GZEbOnogPAQAAAPOz7NQOAAAA
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Length: 607
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache


Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

client_credentials
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--,
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

client_credentials
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

2456f84e8f4:sd87g^lF
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--,
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

client_credentials
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

2456f84e8f4:sd87g^lF
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_secret"

qer+sfggr87qf1gGGRD94f
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--,
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

client_credentials
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

2456f84e8f4:sd87g^lF
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_secret"

qer+sfggr87qf1gGGRD94f
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="resource"

https://management.azure.com/
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

My second request :

```
GET /providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/user@mail.com/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/exports?api-version=2019-01-01 HTTP/1.1
    Host: management.azure.com
    Authorization: Bearer ****
    User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2
    Accept: */*
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Postman-Token: 65deb91a-9cbb-4a4f-afe4-9b9c4e16b1bd,269a4983-a20d-4fa0-abf9-284d05ec59ef
    Host: management.azure.com
    Cookie: __Correlation_SessionId=4fdf1457-269b-4d36-a186-639916ab5d1b
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Connection: keep-alive
    cache-control: no-cache
```

And error I have :

```
    {
    "error": {
        "code": "401",
        "message": "Puid is null/empty. Puid must be present in the header for user to get authorized."
    }
}
```

I didn't already see this error anywhere.

I can't find what's that PUID in Azure.
I also think that I don't put the correct {BillingAccountId}. I don't know how to get it.

Can you guys help me ?

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the Access token i would suggest you to use below end point

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=342fb089-9dg3-46f6-9cfs-4f2164897865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Please ensure to provide the right access to the application.

Additionally for your ease of use you can set a pre-requisite script in postman for getting the token.

Here is the code for the same:

```
var client_id      = pm.environment.get("client_id");
var client_secret = pm.environment.get("client_secret");
var token_endpoint = pm.environment.get("token_endpoint");
var scope          = pm.environment.get("scope");

pm.sendRequest({
    url: token_endpoint,
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
      body: {
          mode: 'formdata',
          formdata: [
            {key: "grant_type"    , value: "client_credentials"}, 
            {key: "client_id"     , value: client_id},
            {key: "client_secret" , value: client_sercret},
            {key: "scope"         , value: scope}      
        ]
      }
},  function(err, response) {
  const jsonResponse = response.json();

  console.log(jsonResponse);

  pm.environment.set("access_token", jsonResponse.access_token);
  console.log(pm.environment.get("access_token"));

});
```

You can refer [this](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/06/setup-postman-to-get-azure-access-tokens-automatically-for-you/) link for postman automation:

Hope it helps.